# Parent process is unable to read data written by child process in pipe

Tags: c, file, pipe, fork

There are many questions related to reading and writing of pipes in this forum, but i am unable to resolve my issue.
The code snippet below, does the following things:

1. Through command line argument filename is passed to the child process through pipe_p
2. Child process opens the file specified, and writes its content to pipe_c for parent process to read and display on the screen.

Everything is working fine, but parent process is unable to read data from the pipe (since it is not printing anything).
I observed that data is successfully written by child process since i am able to print the contents through pipe in child process block but not in parent process.

NOTE : STEP 4 is not working

Anyone please help me this.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int pipe_p[2], pipe_c[2];
    int childpid, c, k = 0;
    char buffer[1000] = {0};
    FILE *file;

    pipe(pipe_p);
    pipe(pipe_c);

    childpid = fork();

    if(childpid){
        //parent process block
        //STEP 1 -------
        close(pipe_p[0]);   //closing reading side of pipe
        write(pipe_p[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        close(pipe_p[1]);
        //--------------
        wait(NULL);
        //--------------
        //printf("%s\n", "Its working");
        //STEP 4 -------
        close(pipe_c[1]);
        read(pipe_c[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        close(pipe_c[0]);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        //--------------
    }
    else{
        //child process block
        //sleep(1);
        //STEP 2 -------
        close(pipe_p[1]);
        read(pipe_p[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        close(pipe_p[0]);
        //printf("%s\n", buffer);
        //--------------

        //STEP 3 -------
        file = fopen(buffer, "r");
        while((c = getc(file)) != EOF){
            buffer[k++] = c;
        }
        buffer[k] = 0;
        //printf("%s", buffer);
        close(pipe_c[0]);
        write(pipe_c[1], buffer, strlen(buffer));
        close(pipe_c[1]);
        //--------------
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see five bugs in this code.  I'm going to list them from least to most important.  I haven't tried to fix any of the bugs, so there may be more that are hidden behind these.

- You forgot to include `sys/wait.h`.  The compiler should have complained about an implicit declaration of `wait`.  (If your compiler did not make any complaints, turn on all the warnings.)
- You are not checking whether any of your system calls are failing.  *Every* system call should be followed by a check for failure.  When one does fail, print to `stderr` a full description of the failure, including the name of the system call that failed, the names of all files involved (if any), and `strerror(errno)` and then exit the program with a nonzero (unsuccessful) exit code.  If you had done this you would have discovered for yourself that, in fact, certain things were *not* "working fine".
- Relatedly, you are not checking whether the child exited unsuccessfully. Instead of `wait(NULL)`, the parent should be doing `waitpid(childpid, &status, 0)` and then decoding the exit status and printing a message to `stderr` for anything other than `WIFEXITED(status) && WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0` and then exiting unsuccessfully itself.
- In the parent, you are calling `wait` in the wrong place.  You need to call `wait` AFTER you have read and processed all of the data from `pipe_c`.  Otherwise, if the child process completely fills up the pipe buffer, the program will deadlock.  (Also, you need to read *all* of the data from the pipe, not just the first 1000 bytes of it.)
- In the child, you have a buffer overrun.  You are reading an unlimited amount of data from the file into `buffer`, but `buffer` has a fixed size.  You should either use `malloc` and `realloc` to enlarge it as necessary, or copy from the file to the pipe in chunks no bigger than the size of `buffer`.

I discovered all of these problems by running the program under the `strace` utility, in `-f` mode (so it traces both sides of the fork), with input from a large file.  This is a valuable debugging technique which you should try for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestions @zwol. I didn't got ur 4th point, here i am making the parent process wait until child finishes populating the buffer (which is done successfully, u can check by uncommenting the printf part in else part). But after returning to parent context, data is not read which getting read in child process, if i copy that STEP 4 in else part.

Comment: Okay i'll check with ur edits. It would be great if u can make the code working. Thank you

Comment: @ChanchalRoshan Fix the buffer overrun in the child, then use a _large_ test file (at least 32KB) and you should see the deadlock from doing the `wait` too early.  Right now, the deadlock is masked by the buffer overrun, which makes the child crash before it can fill up the pipe buffer.

Comment: @ChanchalRoshan Also, If you run your program as-is with a file that is _smaller_ than 1000 bytes, it will appear to work as you intended it to work (that is, the parent will successfully read data from the pipe and print it).

Comment: Yeah, i got ur point about overflow, but it is not working with file that is smaller than 1000 bytes.

Comment: Your unmodified program works for me with a file that is smaller than 1000 bytes.  I strongly recommend you add failure-checking code after every single system call before you try anything else - that will probably reveal why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: With file larger than 1000 bytes it is returning Exit signal: Abort trap ?